# Cannot call AWS StepFunctions in a browser with AWS javascript SDK because of CORS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-step-functions, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to use AWS StepFunctions API in a browser (angular, using aws javascript API).
Using this code:

```
import * as StepFunctions from "aws-sdk/clients/stepfunctions";

   let sf = new StepFunctions({apiVersion: '2016-11-23'});
   var request: GetExecutionHistoryInput = {
       executionArn: executionArn,
       maxResults: 1000,
       reverseOrder: false
   }

   sf.getExecutionHistory(request).promise()
```

I got an error on the browser:

```
 OPTIONS https://states.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ 404 (Not Found)
 Failed to load https://states.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Does it mean that AWS StepFunctions is not ready to be used on the browser side ?
If it's true, where in the AWS documentation is it documented ?

Answer (score 0):

Docs are quite difficult to understand when trying to discern between the standard Javascript SDK, and the Javascript SDK for browsers.

As the question surmises, StepFunctions are effectively unavailable via the browser.

Here is an official statement in a github issue comment:

> The AWS Step Functions service does not support access via CORS
>   requests, so it cannot be used from the browser.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1334#issuecomment-276215833

Perhaps if the Browser SDK didn't link directly to the standard API reference there wouldn't be so much confusion.

Answer (score 0):

CORS support added to AWS Step Functions in May 2021.
So now it's possible to use `@aws-sdk/client-sfn` , here is a very basic TypeScript code:

```
import { SFNClient, DescribeStateMachineForExecutionCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-sfn';
const region = 'us-east-1';
const config = {
  region,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: 'xxxx', // your temporary cred,
    secretAccessKey: 'xxxxx', // your temporary cred,
  },
};
const client = new SFNClient(config);
async function getDataByExecutionArn(arn: string, onChunkRead: any) {
  const command = new DescribeStateMachineForExecutionCommand({ executionArn: arn });
  return await client.send(command);
}
export default getDataByExecutionArn;
```

Just be sure you don’t put those credentials in Javascript running in a browser.